# Date picker in Android

Tags: android, date, picker

Can any one post sample code for a simple date picker in Android.

If date picker is not possible in Android, an option to choose a date is needed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use the DatePicker

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html

It is availible since API Level 1

Here a example how to use the DatePickerDialog.

First add a TextView and a Button to your layout.xml

```
<Button android:id="@+id/myDatePickerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Date"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/showMyDate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Next you have to initialize the Button and TextView in the onCreate Method of your layout.
You need this class variables

```
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;

private TextView mDateDisplay;
private Button mPickDate;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
```

Here the onCreate method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showMyDate);        
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myDatePickerButton);

    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    // get the current date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // display the current date
    updateDisplay();
}
```

UpdateDisplay method:

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    this.mDateDisplay.setText(
        new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                .append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));
}
```

The callback listener for the DatePickDialog

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
```

The onCreateDialog method, called by showDialog()

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
   switch (id) {
   case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
      return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                mDateSetListener,
                mYear, mMonth, mDay);
   }
   return null;
}
```

Hope it helps, used it and it works fine.

Example from

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

Comment: How to use this in a Fragment ?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class dateresult extends Activity
{
private TextView tvdisplaydate;
private DatePicker dpResult;
private Button bntchangedate;

private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);
    setCurrentdateonView();
    addListenerOnButton();

     }
              public void setCurrentdateonView(){

                  tvdisplaydate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
                  dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

                  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                  year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                  month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) ;
                  day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                  tvdisplaydate.setText(new StringBuffer()                   .append(month+1).append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year).append(""));
                  dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);                                  
              }             
             public void addListenerOnButton(){                  
                 bntchangedate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bntchangedate);
                 bntchangedate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

                    }
                });              
             }                
             @Override
            protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 switch(id){

                 case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                     return new DatePickerDialog(this,datePickerLisner,year,month,day);

                 }
                return null;
            }                
             private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerLisner = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int Selectyear,int Selectmonth, int Selectday) {
                    year= Selectyear;
                    month= Selectmonth;
                    day = Selectday;
                    tvdisplaydate.setText(new StringBuilder() 
                    .append(Selectmonth+1).append("-").append(Selectday).append("-").append(Selectyear).append(""));
                            dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);                  
                }
            };
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bntchangedate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Date" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbldate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Current Date (M-D-YYYY) :" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dpResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an updated version which documents backwards compatibility with the Support Library:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker

Answer (score 2):

To use DatePicker add below source code in your OnCreate of Activity.

PS: make sure that **android:focusable="false"** should be provided for your EditText.

```
// Edittext in your layout file
date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
// onclick on edit text
date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
    // date picker dialog
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
         new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                     // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                     date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"+ (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                 }
         }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
    }
});
```

When you click on the Edittext it will open the Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
    //ResidenceActivity date = new ResidenceActivity();
    Handler mHandler ;
    int mDay;
    int mMonth;
    int mYear;

    public DatePickerDialogFragment(Handler h){
        /** Getting the reference to the message handler instantiated in MainActivity class */
        mHandler = h;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        /** Creating a bundle object to pass currently set date to the fragment */
        Bundle b = getArguments();

        /** Getting the day of month from bundle */
        mDay = b.getInt("set_day");

        /** Getting the month of year from bundle */
        mMonth = b.getInt("set_month");

        /** Getting the year from bundle */
        mYear = b.getInt("set_year");

        /** DatePickerDialog's "Set" click listener */
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener  = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
         //   @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mYear = year;

                /** Creating a bundle object to pass currently set date to the fragment */
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

                /** Adding currently set day to bundle object */
                b.putInt("set_day", mDay);

                /** Adding currently set month to bundle object */
                b.putInt("set_month", mMonth);

                /** Adding currently set year to bundle object */
                b.putInt("set_year", mYear);

                /** Adding Current date in a string to bundle object */
                b.putString("set_date", Integer.toString(mDay) + "/" + Integer.toString(mMonth+1) + "/" + Integer.toString(mYear));

                /** Creating an instance of Message */
                Message m = new Message();

                /** Setting bundle object on the message object m */
                m.setData(b);



                /** Message m is sending using the message handler instantiated in MainActivity class */
                mHandler.sendMessage(m);




            }
        };

        /** Opening the DatePickerDialog window */
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I saw this and had to give some feedback. 1. Handler in the constructor Aahh!!!? No. never use constructors with Lifecycled components.
2. Please use constants for Bundle values, less likely to make mistakes.
3. Handlers are a bit of a hack, which wont work if your activity is lifecycled. So maybe look for a better approach to this.

Comment: What is the problem using it (The Handler)?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't handle the user clicking cancel in the date picker. In that case, nothing should be updated.

I wanted the same thing as OP, but I just wanted it in-line. Here's what I used:

Create the callback that will be called when the date picker OK button is clicked:

```
public void datePicked(int year, int month, int day) {
    buttonDate.setText(String.valueOf(year) + "/" + 
          String.valueOf(month) + "/" + String.valueOf(day));
}
```

Then use the following code in the method where you create a button to pick the date:

```
    buttonDate = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_select_date);
    buttonDate.setText("Select Date");
    buttonDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void setReturnDate(int year, int month, int day) {
            datePicked(year, month, day);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activity, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                }
            }, leagueEndDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), leagueEndDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), leagueEndDate
                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            datePickerDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    setReturnDate(((DatePickerDialog) dialog).getDatePicker().getYear(),
                            ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).getDatePicker().getMonth(), ((DatePickerDialog) dialog)
                                    .getDatePicker().getDayOfMonth());
                }
            });
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1 : create a java file:

package com.example.babs;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import  android.app.FragmentManager;


public class EditUserInfo extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_edit_view);

    }

    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


        // pgrm mark ---- ---- ----- ---- ---- ----- ---- ---- -----  ---- ---- -----

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        }

    }


    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "datePicker");
    }

}// end main class EditUserInfo

step 2: your xml file must contain : 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
</ScrollView>
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pick_date" 
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use: import java.util.Calendar;

instead: import android.icu.util.Calendar.

this package supports only for API level-24 not less than that. This is the package we need to use to get Calendar on the dialog box,

this works fine.