# How to set the value of the datePicker in to EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, datepicker, android-datepicker

My XMl Layout is as like below:

```
<RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/dateSelectionLayout"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:visibility="visible">

            <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:singleLine="true" android:id="@+id/dateSelectionEditText" android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="14sp" android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="tax code" android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <DatePicker android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_below="@+id/dateSelectionEditText"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now i want to change the value of the editText that is based on the datePicker date. If User change the date then it should be reflected on the editText at that time. how it is Possible ?

Edited:
I have done like this:
Have set the resourcec like:

```
datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        dateSelectionEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateSelectionEditText);
```

And have set the override method like this:

```
@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    dateSelectionEditText.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+year);

}
```

But still not getting any value on the changing of date picker value.

Edited:

After Kasper Moerch's answer i got the solution. But there is little problem.
I am using this code to init the datepicker.

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
        //dateSelectionEditText.setText( "" + dayOfMonth + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + year );
        datePicker.init(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new MyOnDateChangedListener());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Now with this, I am able to see the changed value from datePicker. But it takes 0 as a First month (from January) instead of the "1". So why it is happend like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is because the value `monthOfYear` is zero based - meaning it goes 0, 1, 2...11 and not 1, 2, 3...12. To fix it just use `(monthOfYear + 1)` when you set the text of the `EditText`. I have edited my answer below to correct the error.

Comment: Yes i have done like that and it works nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is get a reference to the `EditText` and the `DatePicker`:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.dateSelectionEditText );
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById( R.id.datePicker );
```

Then you need to create an `OnDateChangedListener`:

```
private class MyOnDateChangedListener implements OnDateChangedListener {
  @Override
  public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
     editText.setText( "" + dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year );
  }
};
```

All thats left to do is just initialize the DatePicker:

```
datePicker.init( year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, new MyOnDateChangedListener() ).
```

Comment: Should it be reflacted on the EditText if i change the day or month or year of the datePicker ?

Comment: Where should i have to init the datePicker ?

Comment: You should init it right after your get the reference to your `EditText` and `DatePicker`.

Comment: If i am going to init the datePicker after get the reference then i am not able to get the variable year, monthOfYear and dayOfMonth in that init function.

Comment: By Your answer i am near to solution. Just See my Updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [Date pick tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html)

It shows you the best way to implement this. Then you can just change it to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize these variable globally in your activity ,

```
private EditText zopenDate;
        Button calendar;

        private int mYear;
        private int mMonth;
        private int mDay;
        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
```

inside your instance

```
calendar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
zopenDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateSelectionEditText);
```

inside your instance use this listeners,

```
mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                }
            };



calendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });




final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // display the current date (this method is below)
            updateDisplay();
```

the function updatedisplay() outside createInstance(),

```
private void updateDisplay() {
        zopenDate.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

set like this

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        selectedDate = Integer.toString(mMonth)+"/"+Integer.toString(mDay)+"/"+Integer.toString(mYear);
        date_text.setText(selectedDate);
        System.out.println("selected date is:"+selectedDate);
        edittext.setText(selectedDate );
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the back ground for that

Comment: If i change the Value of the Month or date or year then should it be reflacted on the editText ?

Comment: do it date picker through code, if you don't know come to chat room i will tell..

Comment: Please tell me How to set this. as i am not able to get it.

Comment: create date picker dialog through code .. check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299392/date-picker-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Use this to reflect date  in edit text

```
private OnDateSetListener setDOB = new OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                datePicker = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateOB);
                datePicker.setText(" " + dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/"
                        + year + "");

            }
        };
```

Comment: if i change the datePickerValue then should it reflact on the editText at that time.

Comment: i m not sure but try ontouch/onChange event for datePicker