# Birthday formatting

Tags: android, regex

Is it possible to use this regex

```
^([0][1-9] | [1][0-2]) ([0])[1-9][1-2][\d] | [3][0-1]) ([\d]{2})$
```

...inside this code? What I want to do is to restrict entering other characters and at the same time follow the birth date format I want `MM/DD/YY`.

```
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
filters[0] = new InputFilter(){
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (end > start) {

            char[] acceptedChars = new char[]{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','/'};

            for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {                                         
                if (!new String(acceptedChars).contains(String.valueOf(source.charAt(index)))) { 
                    return ""; 
                }               
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

};
txtBirthday.setFilters(filters);
```

I tried using both to restict the user input, whenever I enter special character the editText do not accept it already (which is good) but if I enter lets say 07/27/92 this is valid and should be accepted but the program still says that it is invalid. here's my code maybe there is something wrong with my regex

```
String valid_bday =  "^([0][0-9]|[1][0-2][\b])([0][1-9][1-2]|[3][0-1])([\b]{2})$";
Matcher validbday = Pattern.compile(valid_bday).matcher(Birthday);
//on my else if
else if(!validbday.matches())
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Birth date entered is invalid. \n (MM/DD/YY)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

....I want to have it in MM/DD/YY format. Thanks!

Comment: Use the date picker widget. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299392/date-picker-in-android

Comment: Ahhhhh you updated the question.. normally you should ask another question. By the way why you are using validation here, if the editext provides you the currect input?

Comment: The editText only traps special characters that will enter but it does not follow the regex to trap lets say 13/32/13, 13 is inavalid for month coz we only have 12 months just like the 32 for days coz valid days is just until 31, that's why I use regex to accept correct date even if i'm not using datepicker. I just confused if it is correct "^([0][0-9]|[1][0-2][\b])([0][1-9][1-2]|[3][0-1])([\b]{2})$";

Comment: See my upadted answer for mattcher..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***You need not to use regex validation.***

Android already gives you the way where you can take date entry by using  `android:inputType="date"`.

So add this attribute into your EditText and enjoy..

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="date" >
```

---

And yes as calvin said you can use (better way is) DatePicker. [Date picker in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299392/date-picker-in-android) is a very good example.

---

For mm/dd/yyyy date pattern you should use

`(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/((19|20)\\d\\d)`

this will work. But remember that this is not your final solution. You have to implement validations for those months which doesn't have 31 days or 30 days. [Look here for better understanding.](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-date-with-regular-expression/)