# Calender Event UI android

Tags: android, user-interface, calendar

I can create an event like this:

```
 public void Mindencalendar(){
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Calendar calendarEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
    long idk[] = new long[szam];
    idk[szam-1] = cu.addEventToCalender(cr,"a","b","c",5,calendarEvent.getTimeInMillis());
    szam++;
}
```

...

```
 public class CalendarUtils{
    Context context;
    final int IDF = 12;


    public static long addEventToCalender(ContentResolver cr, String title, String addInfo, String place, int status,
                                          long startDate) {

        String eventUriStr = "content://com.android.calendar/" + "events";
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();


        event.put("calendar_id", 1);
        event.put("title", title);
        event.put("description", addInfo);
        event.put("eventLocation", place);
        event.put("eventTimezone", "UTC/GMT +2:00");
        long endDate = startDate + 1000 * 60 * 60;
        event.put("dtstart", startDate);
        event.put("dtend", endDate);
        event.put("eventStatus", status);
        event.put("hasAlarm", 1);


        Uri eventUri = cr.insert(Uri.parse(eventUriStr), event);
        long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());

        //context.startActivity(i);

        return eventID;
    }
}
```

Now it's writing into the Calendar perfectly and I haven't got a UI but I thought it will open the UI of the basic android calendar. I have to create my own layout if I'd like to do it this way without Intent?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [Date Picker](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker)
Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299392/date-picker-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to fire an intent to send the user to a calendar application, you will have to create your own layout.

Comment: I don't want to use Intent because I cannot set id of the events. It would be the best to use but when I tried to get the event back by id I couldn't do that.

Comment: you can use an observer to follow changes in the calendar and then right after you input a new event, you can fetch the newly added event and fetch his id.

Comment: Can you help me please with this question? This is how I tried to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173525/read-data-from-calendar-by-id]